# Fedora 20 consistent old style (ethx) interface names

Tags: fedora

New Dell Latitude laptop with Fedora 20. One built-in Ethernet interface, one add-in ExpressCard Ethernet interface. I can't seem to get consistent old-style (ethx) interface names.

I've toyed with adding biosdevname=0 and net.ifnames=0 to grub.cfg, creating /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, copying /lib/udev/rules.d/71-biosdevname.rules to /etc/udev/rules.d and uncommenting the branch command, removing the biosdevname RPM package, and creating /etc/modules-load.d/ethernet_drivers.conf with the necessary drivers listed in the right order. No combination seems to get the right result.

If the add-in card is not present, it seems fairly easy to get the built-in port named eth0 as I want. But when the add-in card is present, the best I've been able to get is for it to be named eth0 and the built-in port named eth1. Of course, that is backward and inconsistent.

Here is a summary of my results. Removing the biosdevname package did not change these results.

```
grub2          udev  udev  add-in   Ethernet  Ethernet
biosdevname=0  70    71    present  built-in  add-on  
net.ifnames=0
=============  ====  ====  =======  ========  ========
no             no    mod   no       enp12s0   --
no             no    mod   yes      enp12s0   ens1
no             no    no    no       enp12s0   --
no             no    no    yes      enp12s0   ens1
no             yes   mod   no       enp12s0   --
no             yes   mod   yes      eth0      ens1
no             yes   no    no       enp12s0   --
no             yes   no    yes      eth0      ens1
yes            no    mod   no       eth0      --
yes            no    mod   yes      eth1      eth0
yes            no    no    no       eth0      --
yes            no    no    yes      eth1      eth0
yes            yes   mod   no       eth0      --
yes            yes   mod   yes      eth1      eth0
yes            yes   no    no       eth0      --
yes            yes   no    yes      eth1      eth0
```

Here's the content of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (just two lines).

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="ec:f4:bb:02:44:7a", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:13:3b:00:73:cb", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Here's the content of /etc/modules-load.d/ethernet_drivers.conf (just two lines).

```
tg3
r8169
```

And here's the content of /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth?.

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth0"
UUID="cda65a57-3f30-444d-b041-2e77c056a1b1"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="EC:F4:BB:02:44:7A"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"

TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="eth1"
UUID=722a5c3b-b6e5-44a8-93fa-e0f070059d8c
ONBOOT=no
HWADDR=00:13:3B:00:73:CB
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

Syslog seems to show that the drivers are loaded in the correct sequence. There are also some interface renaming messages.

So what's the right way to accomplish my objective?

Comment: See the FreeDesktop Page on [PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), last section

Comment: AFAIK renaming interfaces to `ethX` was never reliable, making the specific case of swapping `eth0` and `eth1` fragile.

Comment: I would resist the urge to try and force the ethX.

Comment: Add `biosdevname=0` to grub or edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/71-biosdevname.rules` from ` `ENV{UDEV_BIOSDEVNAME}=="1", GOTO="netdevicename_start"` to `ENV{UDEV_BIOSDEVNAME}=="1", GOTO="netdevicename_end"` to avoid interface rename.

Comment: Thanks, @Carter. But I need an answer that works. I've tried all those techniques and I don't get the right result.

Comment: @Pavel, my experience is quite the opposite. Names are consistent not only across boots but across multiple machines with the same configuration, even from different manufacturers. I want that same reliability back again.

Comment: But @nwildner, I've already done that. It doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveClose: This is not about your specific experience but about long known race conditions.